# Averaging maps of Riemannian manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. We know how to average functions $f\colon M\to {\mathbb R}$; the integral $\frac{\int_M f}{\int_M 1}$ returns a value in ${\mathbb R}$. If intead $f\colon M\to {\mathbb R}^n$, then integrating each component of $f$ separately returns a value in ${\mathbb R}^n$.

**What happens if $f\colon M\to N$ and $N$ is again a Riemannian manifold? In which cases can one average maps to $N$ in a canonical way that depends only on the Riemannian structure of $N$?** The value of such averaging should be a point  in $N$.

A possible way of obtaining this value could be to take the minimum in $y\in N$ of the following function $g$:
\begin{equation}g(y) = \int_M d(y,f(x))dx,\end{equation}
and I only expect this minimum to exist and be unique if $M$ is diffeomorphic to a convex subset of ${\mathbb R}^n$ and its Riemannian metric is close to the standard metric (which is the case in which I am interested).

Comment: See http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.2087 and references therein, especially Karcher's paper "Riemannian center of mass and mollifier smoothing".

Comment: @Igor Thanks, that is what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

The anwer to this question follows from Theorem 1.2 in the paper

> Karcher, H. *Riemannian center of mass and mollifier smoothing*.  Comm.
>   Pure Appl. Math. 30 (1977), no. 5, 509–541.

provided by Igor Belegradek in the comments. More specifically, the function on $N$
\begin{equation}
g(y) = \frac{1}{2}\int_M d(y,f(x))^2dx 
\end{equation}
has a unique minimum when $N$ is a convex ball (i.e., for any p,q\in N, there is a unique geodesic between them, and it lies in the ball) and either of the following conditions hold:

- The sectional curvatures at each point of the ball are non-positive,
- The sectional curvatures at each point of the ball are bounded by $\Delta>0$, in which case the radius of the ball should be strictly less than $\frac{1}{2}\pi\Delta^{-1/2}$.